# How to get specific element from list of predicates in Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
?- najveke_pojavuvanja(R).
R = povik(101010, 225).

?- najveke_pojavuvanja(R),povik(X,_).
R = povik(101010, 225),
X = [] .
```

I need to get 101010.
X=101010
Help me!

Comment: Please first start with a clear *problem statement*, and what *you* tried to solve that problem. Right now it is even unclear how input and output relate here.

Comment: When I ask ?-najveke_pojavuvanja(R),povik(X,_).

Comment: I need to get R=povik(101010,225), X=101010

Comment: The query should be `najveke_pojavuvanja(R), R = povik(X,_).` here.